# Hide Specified Row in dc.js rowchart

Tags: javascript, dc.js

Does anyone know a good hack to hide a row from a row chart in crossfilter/dc.js, that is do not chart a particular key.

I want to show some relevantly small %s and hide the 99% which fits in the other category (and prevent a user from filtering on the row).

This doesn't work...as it filters the data

```
function remove_bins(source_group) {
return {
    all:function () {
        return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
            return d.key = 1;
        });
    }
} };
```

var filtered_group = remove_bins(myGroup);

Where I just need to prevent the chart from displaying the huge row. Preferably done within the chart, I expect.

Any ideas welcome!

Ryan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [answered on the user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/dc-js-user-group/4723A31A-A729-4EB8-B728-DE388CDB510B%40woodhull.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer).

Take a look at the FAQ: there is a section about pre-filtering the data. You ought to be able to adapt one of these examples pretty easily.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted

Will add detail here if needed.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - apologies for the double post, I thought I deleted it. I didn't realise I needed the "Ensure Bins Exist Code" in addition to the above.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting point, did you end up chaining the filters or combining them in one? Something to consider when we build a library from these examples.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe filtering the dimension of the row chart with a condition?

```
.dimension(function(d) {  if (d.xxx != "N/A") { return d.Genre ; }})
```

Comment: Sorry but that won't work, it will only put the N/As in a bin with `undefined` as the key.